# How to access an to a value associative array using index position in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

With an associative array such as that one:

```
$fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
```

I tried accessing to a value using :

```
$fruits[2];
```

This gives me a PHP notcie:  Undefined offset;

Is there a way around that ?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want this? Your array does not have the index `2`, its third index is `b`. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @Chris Actually, PHP arrays *are* ordered. :)

Comment: @deceze I need to iterate through 2 arrays at the same time, so i was hoping to use a for loop so that i can do checks like: $array1[$i] == $array2[$i]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not if you want to keep it as an associative array. If you want to use numeric key indexes you could do this:

```
$fruits  = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
$fruits2 = array_values($fruits);

echo $fruits2[2];
```

Find out more about [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) at the PHP manual.

---

UPDATE: to compare two associative arrays as you mentioned in your comment you can do this (if they have the same keys -- if not you should add `isset()` checks):

```
foreach (array_keys($arr1) as $key) {
  if ($arr1[$key] == $arr2[$key]) {
    echo '$arr1 and $arr2 have the same value for ' . $key;
  }
}
```

Or, to avoid the array_keys function call:

```
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $val) {
  if ($val == $arr2[$key]) {
    echo '$arr1 and $arr2 have the same value for ' . $key;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it does answer my question though this solution wont work with what i am trying to do (see comment above), i ll post a more specific question.

Comment: I believe it does ... convert each of the two arrays using array_values() and then compare them like you planned to.

Comment: Thanks for developing on that, i should have mentioned these 2 arrays have different keys. They are the return of a array_count_value function. So their keys are the values of the initial array passed to array_count_values and the values are the number of instance of that value in that array.

Comment: Ah I see -- In that case it seems you could just use the latter two methods with an added check for *if (isset($arr2[$key])) {* ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea.  Without more direct information about your end goal, or larger project I can't speak to any specific implementation.

```
<?php
$fruit = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana', 'c' => 'cranberry');
$flavors = array( 'a' => 'crisp', 'b' => 'mushy', 'c' => 'tart' );

reset($fruit);
reset($flavors);

while (list($key, $val) = each($fruit))
{
    list( $flavorKey, $attribute ) = each( $flavors );

    echo "{$key} => {$val}<br>\n";
    echo "{$attribute}<br><br>\n";
}
```

[edit based on comment about array_count_values]

```
<?

$words = explode( " ", 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy yellow dog' );
$words2 = explode( " ", 'the fast fox jumped over the yellow river' );
$counts = array_count_values( $words );
$counts2 = array_count_values( $words2 );

foreach( $counts as $word => $count )
{
    if ( array_key_exists( $word, $counts2 ) && $counts2[$word] == $counts[$word] )
    {
        echo $word . ' matched.<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah very clever that will actually work in my case as i also need to manipulate the key value. Thanks a lot for this snippet !

Comment: that last code is dumb.  if the key exists, it's going to match. :p